# How do I examine if the function is analytic and calculate the function representation of the function at $z_0=0$?

Tags: power-series

Given is $f(z)=\log(1-\frac{z}{2})$. How do I examine if the function is analytic and calculate the function representation of the function at $z_0=0$?

*What I did:*

The log function is singular at zero, and only at zero. So my function is analytic except where $z= 2$ as $1 - z/2 = 0$ there. I think this is correct.

But how should I do second part?

Comment: What is your function? $\log(1 - z/2)$? Also note that $\log x$ is not even defined for $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Where is the function?